# Animated, smooth-scrolling border-bottom at the menu

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, jquery-hover, floating

my objective is to have effect something like this: http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/ but instead of using additional floating `<li></li>` I wanted to use `border-bottom` property - is it even possible? I've tried to do something like this:

```
$('ul#top_main_menu li a').hover(
    function () {
      $(this).addClass("active").animate(100);
    },
    function () {
      $(this).removeClass("active").animate(100);
    }
  );
```

where `.active` class adds to my `<a href=""></a>` tag `border-bottom: 2px solid #A7E108;` - anyone knows how could I animate it to scroll after hovered element smoothly?

Comment: You should pass an object to `animate` method.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. A border is animated if the element it's bordering is animated. That won't give you the effect you're after.